# get out of "Enter command number" in VSCode

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

While working in vscode,  I sometimes get the terminal popup: "Enter command number:" which I can't seem to exit out of. Does anyone know how? I would normally just restart vscode when this happens.

[image]

Comment: press esc key can exit it. It is windows cmd's function. when press F9 will popup "Enter command number:" .